# argument changes before send to function , python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

It will be easier for me to explain the problem after you see the code :

1st class:

```
class Circuit:
"""creation of a circuit of nodes"""
def __init__ (self):
    self.nodes=dict()
    self.inputs=dict()
    self.outputs=dict()

def add_node_to_circuit(self,x):
     if not isinstance(x, Node):
        raise TypeError('Node expected')

     if not self.nodes.has_key(x):
        self.nodes[x]=None
     else : print "Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed changing nodes in circuit after they created"
```

2nd class :

```
class Node:
def __init__ (self):
    """equals to default constuctor in c + setting the variables
    do not read this constructor directly"""
    self.name=[]
    self.input_one=[]
    self.input_two=[]
    self.output=[]
    self.action=[]
    self.size=0
    ##print "constructor has been read"   self checking
    ##print "constructor self= " ,self
    ##print " with :",name,input_one,input_two,output,action

def read_from_line_anygate(self,line):
    if isinstance(line,list)==False : print "error with line not being a list,anygate"
    self.name=line[0]
    self.input_one=line[1]
    self.input_two=line[2]
    self.output=line[3]
    self.action=line[4]
    self.size=5
def insert_Node(self,line):
    """line needs to be a list type"""
    if len(line)==5 : self.read_from_line_anygate(line)
    elif len(line)==4 : self.read_from_line_gatenot(line)
    else : print "error in insert_Node"
```

main:

```
w=Circuit()

g = open("cir1.gatelevel","r")
x=Node()
for l in g:
    x.insert_Node(l.strip().split())
    w.add_node_to_circuit(x)

##print "read gate level file done" self checking
g.close()
```

As you might see I have some other methods but they are very intuitive, except i got also **str** and **repr** for class Node.
My problem is that in main , except for the 1st iteration , whenever x change immediately w.nodes changes to it before even the line of w.add_node_to_circuit has been read , checked with debugger,and moreover it deletes the last key that was in the dictionary nodes instead of adding it to the ones exists.
Also I try to print in main w.nodes , w.input, w.output this is what i get :

```
 Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed changing nodes in circuit after they created
Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed changing nodes in circuit after they created
Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed changing nodes in circuit after they created
Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed changing nodes in circuit after they created
Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed changing nodes in circuit after they created
Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed changing nodes in circuit after they created
Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed     changing nodes in circuit after they created
Node already exist .error in add node to circuit because user not allowed             changing nodes in circuit after they created
{['X_c2_d3', '_c2_net3', 'inp3', '_net3', 'NAND']: None}
{'inp1': None, 'inp3': None, 'inp2': None}
{'outp': None, '_outp2': None, '_outp3': None}
```

I am using python 2.7 .

Comment: Why does `Node` have an `insert_Node` method? And why do you keep trying to add the `x` node to `w`?

Comment: As for the first part of the question I am trying build it somewhat like a graph or a tree or a forest(in the end I want it to solve me a logic gate circuit ). I agree the name insert_Node isn't the best one but what other options do I have? to do it in the init?
For the 2nd part , I wanted to get in the end 3 dictionaries , one for inputs one for output and one that will contain all the nodes in my circuit.
I still haven't figure it all out but
the next step from there will be to created another class ,wire, which wll connect the nodes from one to other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not creating a new nodes in main, but modify `x` each time. Since it is passed as a reference, it is always the same. To avoid that, you would need to create `x` inside the loop:

```
w=Circuit()

g = open("cir1.gatelevel","r")
    for l in g:
        x=Node()
        x.insert_Node(l.strip().split())
        w.add_node_to_circuit(x)
```

Comment: You got it, it's now working ,thanks.
I also got a follow up question to this , In C/C++ I can see immediately if an argument is sent by value or pointer or reference . How can I see the difference between them in python?

Comment: @maor in Python *everything* is passed by reference. If it's an immutable object you'll never see any side effects, but if it's mutable you need to be careful either to not modify it or to make a copy.

Comment: @maor: If you're used to C++ variable semantics, you might find the following article useful: https://rg03.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/semantics-of-python-variable-names-from-a-c-perspective/

Comment: I would also recommend networkx for anything related to graph theory. I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to say for sure, but networkx is a very versatile graph theory module